# cURL web request combined with cmd

Tags: c#, http, curl, cmd

Good day everyone

At the moment I am working on a program which uses curl. I got the following code (simplified and slightly changed):

```
    string path = @"N:\Privat\Dokumente\Curl\openssl\curl.exe";
    string cmdcommand = path + " " + "-k" + "https://lets_pretend_this_is_an_url";
```

This command would then by passed to the cmd via processes. What I want now is, that I don't need curl installed on my pc to execute the command. I already heard something about cURL but I couldn't find anything cmd related. I'm looking forward for some help :)

Comment: You want to use curl without having it on your PC? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can use curl online and compose your command : http://onlinecurl.com/